# How to get JSON data from the text?

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have a string, something like this:

> sometext{"points":{"point":[{"lat":"55.68705772049725","lon":"21.127218855544925"},{"lat":"55.68714472465217","lon":"21.127141742035747"},{"lat":"55.6871934235096","lon":"21.12712439149618"},{"lat":"55.68733625113964","lon":"21.127151465043426"},{"lat":"55.68751168437302","lon":"21.12717761658132"},{"lat":"55.687646800652146","lon":"21.127120200544596"},{"lat":"55.68781033158302","lon":"21.127034788951278"},{"lat":"55.687981490045786","lon":"21.12691568210721"}]}}sometext

Is it possible with `regex` extract `JSON` in `Javascript`?

P.S.
I get a lot of data and joining it in to the string. So i need to get json from that string as there can be the end of firs object and the beginning of other

Comment: Why? `JSON.parse` not good enough?

Comment: @Jon `JSON.parse()` will throw `SyntaxError: Unexpected token s` on this example.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't remove `sometext` from the beginning and end of the string before passing it to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: He means extract the content that is JSON from a larger, random string, I think

Comment: I get a lot of data and joining it in to the string. So i need to get json from that string as there can be the end of firs object and the begining of other

Comment: @Kirix: If you are concatenating JSON objects together and you are in control of that process make a valid JSON array string of those objects instead of an arbitrary string concatenation. You need to clarify what the whole format is, especially the `sometext` part. Answers are now assuming that you have one JSON object in a semi-random string (`sometext` parts don't contain any of `[,{,},]`), which might not be true in your case.

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you don't have braces outside of the JSON part, and supposing that what is encoded is an object as in your example (not an array), then you may do

```
var obj = JSON.parse(s.match(/({.*})/)[1]);
```

If you have braces outside, you'll have to look for a more reliable way to detect the start and end of the JSON part.

Comment: What about square brackets? `[55.68714472465217, 21.127141742035747]` is also valid JSON.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I mentioned that in my answer. I guess that OP is trying, as in his example, to parse a specific object encoded in JSON. If OP says he might have to deal with top level arrays, then I'll make a more complex answer.

Comment: the problem is that i cant find this solution.

Comment: @Kirix What do you mean exactly ? Do you have more than one JSON text in your text ? Do you have top level arrays ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'sometext{"points":{"point":[{"lat":"55.68705772049725","lon":"21.127218855544925"},{"lat":"55.68714472465217","lon":"21.127141742035747"},{"lat":"55.6871934235096","lon":"21.12712439149618"},{"lat":"55.68733625113964","lon":"21.127151465043426"},{"lat":"55.68751168437302","lon":"21.12717761658132"},{"lat":"55.687646800652146","lon":"21.127120200544596"},{"lat":"55.68781033158302","lon":"21.127034788951278"},{"lat":"55.687981490045786","lon":"21.12691568210721"}]}}sometext';

var object = JSON.parse(str.match(/({.*})/).pop());
```